# What is the problem of those `if` statements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code in Angular in my component:

```
  i=18;

 

   
  onScrollDown(evt:any) {
   
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.i)
      this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty}) => {
        if (evt.index === 0) {
          this.beu=beuty.slice(0,this.i+=15);
          console.log('hello');
        }  
        if(evt.index===1){
          this.tools=tool.slice(0,this .i+=15);
        }
 
      })
    },1000);
   

  }
```

and this code is in my template:

```
<mat-tab-group   mat-align-tabs="start"  (selectedTabChange)="onScrollDown($event)">
```

My problem is those `if` statements do not work and I do not see `hello` in the console after scrolling.

What is the problem of those `if` statements?

Comment: Maybe try to use try...catch statement, I think it might be a problem with the API call

Comment: "after scrolling"???? selectedTabChange happens when the tab selection has changed.

Answer (score -1):

i wouldnt use 2 if, but if {} else if {}

i=18;

onScrollDown(evt:any) {

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log(this.i)
  this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty}) => {
    if (evt.index === 0) {
      this.beu=beuty.slice(0,this.i+=15);
      console.log('hello');
    }  
    else if(evt.index===1){
      this.tools=tool.slice(0,this .i+=15);
    }

  })
},1000);
```

}